# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yield' of undefined

Tags: d3.js, typeerror

I keep getting this error message,

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yield' of undefined".

The strange thing is that I copied the code form someone else and they didn't have this issue, so any insights would be great..thx!

Below is the code; the specific error is on the second line from the bottom, 
 variety["YoY"] = variety.values[1].yield - variety.values[0].yield;

---

```
d3.tsv("barley.tsv", function(error, data) {

  console.log(data);

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.site = d.site.replace(" ","").replace(". ", "")
    d.variety = d.variety.replace(" ","").replace(". ", "")
    d["third_level_node"] = d.site + "-" +  d.variety + "-" + d.year;
    d["second_level_node"] = d.site + "-" + d.variety
    d["first_level_node"] = d.site
  })

  var nestedBarley = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.site })
      .key(function(d) { return d.variety })
      .entries(data);

  var yoyLookup = {};
  nestedBarley.forEach(function(site) {
        site.values.forEach(function(variety) {
          variety["YoY"] = variety.values[1].yield - variety.values[0].yield;
          yoyLookup[site.key + "-" + variety.key] = variety["YoY"]
        })
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to see your data to know for definite.

If you want more insight yourself shove in a quick console.log after `nestedBarley.forEach(function(site) {` :

```
console.log ("variety values", variety.values);
```

If that produces undefined values or, my hunch*, occasional arrays of length 1 then that's your issue.

*My hunch being your nesting is producing some entries with only a single value - maybe some of your barley site/variety combos only have data for a single year/instance -, so calling variety.values[1] is going to be undefined in those cases